# Magento 2, how to change 'text-box' to 'select-list' of customer edit grid?

Tags: magento2.2, customer, adminhtml, grid, edit

Using `magento 2.2`, `admin`, `customer -> all customer [Edit Panel]`. I want to **change ZIP control** from  *text-field* to *select-list*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> app/code/SR/Stackexchange/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns">
        <column name="billing_postcode" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="70">
            <settings>
                <options class="SR\Stackexchange\Model\Source\Postcode"/>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">ZIP</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> app/code/SR/Stackexchange/Model/Source/Postcode.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\Stackexchange\Model\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class Postcode implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $options;

    /**
     * Get options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        if ($this->options !== null) {
            return $this->options;
        }

        $options[] = [
            'label' => '90034',
            'value' => '90034',
        ];
        $options[] = [
            'label' => '90035',
            'value' => '90035',
        ];
        $options[] = [
            'label' => '49628-7978',
            'value' => '49628-7978',
        ];
        $this->options = $options;

        return $this->options;
    }
}
```